# How to get around Heroku slug size limits?

Tags: sqlite, heroku, datasette

I'm working with a Python-based library called "[datasette](https://github.com/simonw/datasette)" that makes it easy to search SQLite databases. I'm trying to push more than 1.5GB worth of SQLite databases, 535MB compressed, to Heroku but I get this error when I run `datasette publish heroku`.

```
Compiled slug size: 535.5M is too large (max is 500M).
```

How can I work around the slug size limits?

Comment: Host the SQLite somewhere like S3, and have your instances fetch it when they start up?

Comment: How would one use Cloudcube in conjunction with datasette?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get around Heroku's slug size limits, and there doesn't appear to be any way to use Datasette with a client-server database.

Either reduce the amount of data you're trying to ship or find another host.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Run is a very inexpensive alternative to Heroku which doesn't have size limits. You can use it with Datasette like this: https://datasette.readthedocs.io/en/stable/publish.html#publishing-to-google-cloud-run