# How to deploy a pre-trained model on Heroku, with large files?

Tags: python, heroku, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, sentiment-analysis

In python 3, I started using a pre-trained model for Sentiment Analysis, [multilingual XLM-roBERTa-base model](https://huggingface.co/cardiffnlp/twitter-xlm-roberta-base-sentiment?text=%F0%9F%A4%97). On my computer, for example, I downloaded the model and added more data to improve the training database
For example, locally my model folder has these files:

```
config.json
pytorch_model.bin
sentencepiece.bpe.model
special_tokens_map.json
tokenizer.json
tokenizer_config.json
```

With this script below I can use this model, example of evaluating a sentence:

```
from transformers import pipeline, AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification

path = "app\\"
model_name = "roberta" #this points to the folder where the files are on my computer

model = f"{path}{model_name}"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model)
clf = pipeline("text-classification", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
answer = clf("Este es un ejemplo")
print(answer)
```

My intention now is to deploy this pre-trained model to an app on Heroku. Please does anyone know what alternatives I could use for this? And possible tutorials, ways to do this

On Heroku I have an app "web gunicorn app:server". I don't know if this is also feasible, because the model files on my computer are big, pytorch_model.bin for example is 1 GB

Edited:
My question is not just about size limits on Heroku, as this question has already been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640234/how-to-get-around-heroku-slug-size-limits)

I really want to know how to deploy a big Sentiment Analysis model on Heroku. What ways could I do this

Comment: "My question is not just about size limits on Heroku, as this question has already been asked… I really want to know how to deploy a big Sentiment Analysis model on Heroku. What ways could I do this"—if your model is 1GB there is no reasonable way to deploy it on Heroku. Choose another host.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have other suggestions? Or tutorials? I had thought of Heroku because I've already worked with it and made the website that I'm going to use on it